# Create diamond overlay image using css

Tags: html, css, styles, overlay

How can I build something like below using css? I want to have a diamond cut-out of an image that does always follow the color of the background.

[image: Diamond overlay]

Comment: u can use any photo editing software like Photoshop and then after editing use the picture.

Comment: no i need to create it using css. i have one way to do it, but i think its not best solution.

Comment: What way r u talking about  ??

Comment: hey did u tried the css clip property ?

Comment: I have voted to reopen the question, considering this is (a) a real problem people keep coming back for via google and (b) it is answerable.

Answer (score 11):

What I want to add to Lloan's answer: If you want the images to stay with the orientation they had and simply cut out a diamond shape out of them, you'll need to do things slightly different.

In the example below, square is the diamond shape that is visible. Pic is nested in there so that 'square' can properly cut off the edges of the image that is used. This way, we can rotate the "square" to be a diamond, and rotate the picture back to it's original orientation.

```css
body {
  /* To show the background color is no problem here */
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 25px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.pic {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/150/150);
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -25px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <div class="pic">

  </div>
</div>
```